# $_Post doesn't take the info from form into the array

Tags: php, post

My $_Post doesn.t work. When I print it with var_dump it says 0 items in the array. here is the code

```
<form method = "post" action = "contact-process.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for = "name">Name</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for = "email">Email</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type = "text" name = "email" id = "email">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for = "message" >Message</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <textarea name = "message" id = "message" ></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Send">
    </form>


<?php
     var_dump($_POST);
     $name = $_POST["name"];
     $email = $_POST["email"];
     $message = $_POST["message"];
echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $message; ?>
```

This is the html code for my form and the contact-process.php code 
The var_dump command returns 0 items and echo-ing the variables returns undefined index :'name', 'email' , 'message'

Comment: Please show your HTML code.

Comment: Check first `isset($_POST)`

Comment: That's because until the form is submitted their is no post data. And since you don't check to see if there was a form submission that code *always* executes.

Comment: I have checked isset($_POST) like so : var_dump(isset($_POST)); and It returns boolean true.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump return 0 because it does not have any elements when it firstly loads. So put a condition to check weather the submit button is clicked or not.

You need to specify a name attribute to for checking.

```
<form method = "post" action = "contact-process.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for = "name">Name</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for = "email">Email</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type = "text" name = "email" id = "email">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for = "message" >Message</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <textarea name = "message" id = "message" ></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Send" name="submit">
    </form>  


        <?php
                if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
                {   
                     var_dump($_POST);
                     $name = $_POST["name"];
                     $email = $_POST["email"];
                     $message = $_POST["message"];

                     echo $name;
                     echo $email;
                     echo $message;
                } 
            ?>
```

I hope this gonna do your job. :)